# Laravel API pass to Vuejs query join nested transaction and order Ttbles

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js

I am creating a shopping cart and i have 3 tables here as you can see in the image. first is the products, orders and last the transactions, all products that has been ordered will be place in order table along with transaction id whoever belongs to that transaction, and transaction table would record the total balance and change and i want to fetch it in database using laravel query builder and convert it to json like in the 2nd image below, i hope my explanation is not that confusing. Thanks in advance guys :)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps below:

**1.Creating models and adding relationship between them.**

You can create models for transaction , order & product using phpartisan.

```
php artisan make:model Transaction
php artisan make:model Order
php artisan make:model Product
```

configure them according to your mysql tables structure.

**Adding relationships.**

Transaction Model

```
public function order(){
  return $this->hasOne(Order::class, 'transaction_id', 'id');
}
```

Order Model

```
public function transaction(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Transaction::class);
}

public function products(){
  return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'id', 'product_id');
}
```

Product Model

```
public function order(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
}
```

**2.Creating a controller to handle the results.**

You can create a controller using phpartisan.

```
php artisan make:controller TransactionController -r
```

**Setting up our controller.**

```
public function TransactionDetails($transactionID){

   $transaction = Transaction::where('id',$transactionID)->firstOrFail();
   $order = $transaction->order;
   $products = $order->products;

   $result = array();
   $result['transaction'] = $transaction;
   $result['transaction']['order'] = $order;
   $result['transaction']['order']['products'] = $products;

   return response()->json($result);

}
```

This should work and give you your desired output , if any error occurs let me know.

Comment: Can't thank you enough sir for helping me! thank you so much sir :D

Comment: Your welcome , let me know if you need help with anything else. have a nice day.

Comment: Can i ask again sir? how to fetch this with axios? i mean what should be the proper code like would res.data is enough to assign it to a object with an empty array?

Comment: Yes , i personally use ajax and the procedure is same in both for storing api responses.

Comment: the relationships you have created are wrong, @AmirQureshi. take look at the table structure again. A `Transaction` has many `Orders`, A `Order` belongs to one `Transaction`, A `product` has many `Orders` and an `Order` belongs to one `Product`.

Comment: nothing is wrong , i have made the relationships according to the response wanted. In the response image 1 transaction has 1 order and 1 order has many products.changes might be required in the mysql database only if needed.

Comment: sir i would like to say that 1 transaction can be place in many order sir

Comment: Then you can replace 'hasOne' in transaction model's order function with 'hasMany'.

Answer (score 1):

generating models.

```
php artisan make:model Transaction
php artisan make:model Order
php artisan make:model Product
```

**TransactionModel**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'transaction_id', 'id');
}
```

**ProductModel**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order:class, 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

**OrderMode**

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id', 'id');
}

public function transaction()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Transaction::class, 'transaction_id', 'id');
}
```

You can create a `ResourceCollection` to generate your desired JSON output.

```
php artisan make:resource TransactionCollection
```

this will create a `ResourceCollecion` in `app\Http\Resource\TransactionCollection`

**TransactionCollection**

```
class TransactionCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $transactions = [];

        foreach($this->collection as $transaction) {

            $jsonTransaction = [
                'id'     => $transaction->id,
                'date'   => $transaction->transaction_date,
                'total'  => $transaction->transaction_total,
                'change' => $transaction->transaction_change,
                'orders' => []
            ];

            foreach($transaction->orders as $order) {

                $product = $order->product;

                array_push($jsonTransaction['orders'], [
                    'id'           => $order->id,
                    'product_name' => $product->product_name,
                    'category'     => $product->product_category,
                    'price'        => $order->order_price,
                    'quantity'     => $order->order_quantity
                ]);
            }

            array_push($transactions, $jsonTransaction);
        }
    }
}
```

**TransactionController**

```
public function getAllTransactions()
{
    // this will return your desired json result as you posted in the question.
    return TransactionCollection::make(Transaction::all());
}
```

Comment: sir it has an error and it says that "message": "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()",

Comment: If you used Amir Qureshi answer to create models, there are some mistakes in those relationships. thats why. lets see what's his response .

Comment: I updated my answer and included the model creations too, If that helps you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182216/discussion-between-unknown-and-tharaka-dilshan).